# Java8 LocalDateTime and NANO_OF_SECOND strange formatting

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, datetime-format, java-time

I try this code:

```
import java.time.*; 
...
   LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
   DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
                                    "dd-MMM-yyyy  HH:mm:ss.n");
   System.out.format("Now = %s %n", now.format(formatter));
```

in order to get an output with subsecond information
`Now = 12-Apr-2018  14:47:38.039578300`

Unfortunately, in the first 100 ms of every second, the leading zero of the subsecond information is omitted and I get a very misleading output `Now = 12-Apr-2018  14:47:38.39578300` , which can be easily misinterpreted as about 38.4 sec, or 396 ms after the full second, instead of the real 38.04 sec.

The only workarond I found, is a format of `ss.nnnnnnnnn` with exactly 9 `n`, to get my desired output.

**Edit**:

There is something nicer, which I missed in this area when posting this question.

I'm not really interested in Nanoseconds, but a fractional part of seconds (about ms resolution), is what I'm really looking for.

Then, this one is much more suitable

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss.SSS");
```

The capital S indicates the number of subsecond digits, including leading zeros of course.

Comment: okay what is the question?

Comment: If the edit answers the question, you can add an answer and rollback the edit.

Comment: Stackexchange frightened me: "Do you really want to answer your own question? What about rather editing the question?" So the remaining question is about the difference between `.n` and `.S`
@jonpebs already supplied the answer, so I do not need to give it myself any more.

Comment: New users sometimes post their comments as answers, which is not desired. I suppose this is why a warning message is given there. Answering one’s own question is welcomed and not that uncommon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want just ms resolution, you can use `S` instead of `n`:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter
    .ofPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy  HH:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.US);
```

This will print just the first 3 fractional digits (which is ms resolution):

> 12-Apr-2018 14:47:38.039

Note that I used a `java.util.Locale` to define the language to be used for the month name. That's becase the JVM might not always be set to English, and the results can't be what you expect. Ex: my JVM is set to Portuguese and the month name is "abr". Setting a specific locale eliminates this problem.

---

To print all the 9 digits, using either `nnnnnnnnn` or `SSSSSSSSS` will work.

---

We can see why it behaves like this when we [check the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns). `S` and `n` have different presentations:

```
Symbol  Meaning                     Presentation      Examples
------  -------                     ------------      -------
S       fraction-of-second          fraction          978
n       nano-of-second              number            987654321
```

`S` is a *fraction*, while `n` is a *number*. The docs tell you the difference:

> **Number**: If the count of letters is **one**, then the value is output using the **minimum number of digits** and **without padding**.
>
> **Fraction**: Outputs the nano-of-second field as a fraction-of-second. The nano-of-second value has nine digits, thus the count of pattern letters is from 1 to 9. **If it is less than 9**, then the nano-of-second value is **truncated**, with **only the most significant digits being output**.

So, just 1 `n` will print the value without padding (without the `0` in the beginning), leading to the wrong output you've got, while `SSS` will give you the correct output.

Answer (score 7):

To get better control of fractions you can use the builder, not just pattern letters. Specifically [appendFraction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendFraction-java.time.temporal.TemporalField-int-int-boolean-).

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
  .appendPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy  HH:mm:ss")
  .appendFraction(ChronoField.NANO_OF_SECOND, 1, 9, true)
  .toFormatter();
```

Pattern letter "n" is rarely what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is anything better than `nnnnnnnnn`. As [per DateTimeFormatter docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) for `n` pattern the leading zeros will be truncated if less than 9 pattern letters are used:

> Fraction: Outputs the nano-of-second field as a fraction-of-second.
>   The nano-of-second value has nine digits, thus the count of pattern
>   letters is from 1 to 9. If it is less than 9, then the nano-of-second
>   value is truncated, with only the most significant digits being
>   output.

`n` and `N` are the only nano fields supported by DateTimeFormatter.

Comment: Thanks. But I noticed the .S format pattern too late. This is probably what I'm after: Fraction of second digits.

Comment: Just for clarify, the `n` symbol's presentation is `number` (in the doc). So, you mentioning the rules for `Fraction` doesn't apply to `n`